# Finding data points (coordinates) from datasets which are close to target dataset

Tags: python, gis

I have multiple csv files which consist of latitude and longitude data of cars traveling through different paths. I want compare and check about which car travelled same path as of my targeted car path.
Later I would like to exclude/delete coordinates which do not fall under tolerance of my targeted car path and plot all files data in one graph(to check if only those coordinates are kept which are in line with targeted car path.
I understand that the question might be confusing but I cannot attach dataset because of data security reason.
I am new to python and GIS domain. Please excuse for any stupid questions.

Comment: Please divide into steps. E.G. 1. filter trajectories 2. Plot trajectories etc.

Comment: I see what you want to achieve. But what is your question? What do you expect to receive as answer?

Answer (score 0):

Did a simple script to try to help you, check if you understand it and if it helps you:

```
import math

car_path = [(1, 1), (2,2), ( 3,3)] #tuples of position
gps_path = [(1.1, 1.2), (2.1, 2.2), (3.01, 3.01)]

TOLERANCE = 0.1 #your tolerance constant


for i in range(len(car_path)):
  distance = math.dist(car_path[i], gps_path[i])
  print(distance )
  
  if (dist < TOLERANCE):
    print("Point on track")
  else:
    print("Out of track")
```

Output:

```
0.22360679774997896
Out of track
0.22360679774997919
Out of track
0.01414213562373065
Point on track
```